# Away3D vs Papervision3D

Tags: 3d, browser-based-games

I have served Google and I found that there are many 3D game engine also I have another question here

[Do Playfish and Zynga use Flash game engines?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22208/do-playfish-and-zynga-use-flash-game-engines)

and I know that away3D is used for social media games on Facebook

but I'm confused now which one is the best and will be good and easy to start with as I'm very new in game development

so if anyone can advice me I will be thankful

also if anyone can support me with tutorial or book that may help me this is will be great

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't be looking at what other companies use but focus more on what you're going to do with the 3D engine. Think of what your game idea will need and then compare the features of each engines. Then play a day or more with the top 3 on your list and only then decide :).

Answer (score 1):

The majority of social media flash games do not use a 3D engine at all. They are mostly 2D games (including fake 3D like isometric etc.).

That being said, Papervision3D is basically dead. There hasn't been much upgrades for this engine. Away3D is still actively developed, so are other engines like [Yogurt3D](http://www.yogurt3d.com/) or [Alternativa](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/).

But since [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) now also allows you to publish a SWF, this is probably the easiest way to create a 3D game that runs in the flash player.